# android studio - prebuilt .so files in jniLibs disappear every time i make the project

Tags: android-ndk

[image]

I use Android Studio 1.5. I use ndk and I write my .so file and that's OK. The problem: I need some other prebuilt .so files I wrote with vim. I just put the .so files in the jniLibs/armeabi-v7a. However, whenever I make the project, the other prebuilt .so files disappear, and only the one I write with ndk stays.

Does the problem come from the content I write in Android.mk or build.gradle? In build.gradle, I write sourceSets.main.jni.srcDirs = [].

Could anyone help?